# HTTP-Download - sometimes file is not downloaded complete without error

Tags: java, file, download, inputstream, outputstream

I'm trying to develope a small Java Downloader. But sometimes, i can not find out when, one download is missing a few percent. After one download is corrupt every download after it will also be corrupt. I have no clue where is my problem, and tried some different output buffers but with no success. Here is the source of the download thread:

```java
    private void startDownload() {
        try {
            ins = null;
            outb=null;
            setRunning(true);
            // Erstelle HttpURLConnection Objekt zur Anfrage an den Server
            con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", DataController.getInstance().getUserAgentString());
            if (DataController.getInstance().getCookie() != null) {
                con.setRequestProperty("Cookie", DataController.getInstance().getCookie());
            }

            System.out.println("saveto length: " + this.saveTo );
            System.out.println("loaded bytes : " + loadedbytes );

            if (loadedbytes > 0) {
                // Ist Zieldatei noch vorhanden und stimmt die Größe?
                if (saveTo != null && saveTo.exists() && saveTo.length() == loadedbytes) {   // SAVE TO NULL!!!
                    // Wiederaufnahme-Position übermitteln
                    con.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + loadedbytes + "-");
                }
                else if (!saveTo.exists()) {
                    // Zieldatei existiert nicht (mehr)
                    try {
                        if (!saveTo.createNewFile()) {
                            // Zieldatei konnte nicht angelegt werden

                            // saveTo-Objekt zurücksetzen und somit Save-Dialog provozieren
                            saveTo = null;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // Beim Anlegen des Files ist ein unerwarteter Fehler aufgetreten
                        e.printStackTrace();

                        // saveTo-Objekt zurücksetzen und somit Save-Dialog provozieren
                        saveTo = null;
                    } 
                }
            }
            con.connect();

            // Prüfe Response-Code
            rc = con.getResponseCode();

            if (DataController.getInstance().isDebugMode()) System.out.println("rc " + rc);

            if (rc == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK || rc == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_PARTIAL) {

                // Wenn keine 206 Partial Content kam, loaded-Zähler zurücksetzen, download von vorne beginnen
                if (rc == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                    loadedbytes = 0;
                }

                String filename = getFileName();

                if (loadedbytes == 0) {
                    size = Long.valueOf(con.getHeaderField("Content-Length")).longValue();
                } else {
                    size = loadedbytes + Long.valueOf(con.getHeaderField("Content-Length")).longValue();
                }

                // Fortschritts-Event an alle Abonnenten senden
                for (DownloadProgressListener l: progressListeners) {
                    l.setMinimum(0);
                    l.setMaximum(size);
                    l.setValue(loadedbytes);
                    l.setFilename(filename);
                    l.setStatus(DownloadProgressListener.STATUS_RUNNING);
                }

                // Autosave - Wenn defaultSavePath gesetzt, baue Dateipfad zusammen
                if (saveTo == null && DataController.getInstance().getSettingsController().getDefaultSavePath() != null 
                    && DataController.getInstance().getSettingsController().getUseDefaultSavePath()) {

                     File saveTmp = new File(DataController.getInstance().getSettingsController().getDefaultSavePath(), filename);

                     // Prüfe auf Gültigkeit, wenn gültig - übernehmen
                     if (saveTmp.exists() || saveTmp.createNewFile()) {
                         saveTo = saveTmp;

                         // Filename-Event auslösen, damit Server den "neuen" Zielpfad mitgeteilt bekommt
                         for (DownloadProgressListener l: progressListeners) {
                             l.setFilename(saveTo.getName());
                         }
                     }
                }

                // Wurde der Speicherort (immer)noch nicht festgelegt?
                if (saveTo == null) {

                    // Speichern-Unter Dialog öffnen
                    FileDialog dia = new FileDialog(ViewController.getFrame(), "Save as", FileDialog.SAVE);
                    dia.setFile(filename);
                    dia.setVisible(true);

                    //System.out.println("now: " + new Date().getTime());

                    if (dia.getFile() == null) {
                        // User hat Abbrechen gedrückt - Download abbrechen und aus der Liste entfernen
                        if (DataController.getInstance().isDebugMode()) 
                            System.out.println("download cancelled");

                        DataController.getInstance().removeDownload(url);
                        return;
                    }

                    // Settings-Panel bescheidsagen, dass ein Pfad ausgewählt wurde -> DefaultSavePath-Haken anzeigen
                    DataController.getInstance().getSettingsController().setLastSavePath(new File(dia.getDirectory()));

                    saveTo = new File(dia.getDirectory(), dia.getFile());

                    if (DataController.getInstance().isDebugMode())
                        System.out.println("Saving to " + saveTo.getAbsolutePath());


                    // Neuen Dateinamen an Event-Abonnenten propagieren
                    for (DownloadProgressListener l: progressListeners) {
                        l.setFilename(saveTo.getName());
                    }

                }
                // Erstelle einen neuen Thread, der nun unabhängig von der Oberfläche im Hintergrund den Download abarbeitet
                downloadThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            try {
                                // Netzwerk-Stream öffnen
                                //ins = con.getInputStream();
                                // Dateiausgabe-Stream öffnen, rc == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_PARTIAL => append
                                // outb = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(saveTo, rc == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_PARTIAL));
                                outb = new FileOutputStream(saveTo, rc == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_PARTIAL);
                                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(outb);
                                bis = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
                                loadedbytes = saveTo.length();
                                byte data [] = new byte[1024];
                                int count;
                                long bytesread = 0;
                                long lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                long now = 0;
                                int bytespersecond = 0;
                                long timediff = 0;
                                int timeleft = 0;
                                System.out.println("First Size loadedbytes "+loadedbytes);
                                // Lese-Schleife
                                //for (count = ins.read(data,0,1024); count >= 0; count = ins.read(data,0,1024))
                                while (( count = bis.read(data,0,1024)) > -1 )
                                {
                                    // Wenn download pausiert oder abgebrochen -> Schleife abbrechen 
                                    if (stop || paused) break;

                                    // Daten schreiben, zähler erhöhen
                                    bos.write(data,0,count);
                                    bytesread += count;
                                    loadedbytes += count;
                                    now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                    timediff = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime;
                                    // Mehr als 1 Sekunde vergangen
                                    if (timediff > 1000L) {

                                        // Geschwindigkeit und Restzeit berechnen
                                        bytespersecond = (int)Math.round(((double)bytesread / (timediff)) * 1000.0);
                                        bytesread = 0;
                                        lastTime = now;
                                        timeleft = (int)Math.round((double)(size - loadedbytes) / bytespersecond);

                                        // Fortschritts-Events auslösen
                                        for (DownloadProgressListener l: progressListeners) {
                                            l.setValue(loadedbytes);
                                            l.setSpeed(bytespersecond);
                                            l.setTimeEstimated(timeleft);
                                        }
                                        ViewController.refreshMainProgress();
                                    }
                                }
                                //Date timer = new Date();
                                // Ausgabe- und Netzwerk-Stream beenden
                                System.out.println("geladen: " + loadedbytes);
                                bos.flush();
                                bos.close();
                                bis.close();
                                outb.flush();
                                outb.close();
                                ins.close();
                                for (DownloadProgressListener l: progressListeners) 
                                {
                                    l.setStatus(DownloadProgressListener.STATUS_CHECKSUM_VERIFY);
                                }
                                ViewController.refreshMainProgress();

                                if (!paused) {

                                        // wurde abgebrochen?
                                        if (stop) {

                                            // Zieldatei löschen, zähler zurücksetzen
                                            saveTo.delete();
                                            saveTo = null;
                                            loadedbytes = 0;
                                            stop = false;
                                        }
                                        urlMD5 = DataController.getURLMD5(url.toString());
                                        fileMD5 = DataController.getMD5(saveTo.getCanonicalPath());
                                        if(fileMD5!=null && !fileMD5.equals("") 
                                                && urlMD5!=null && !urlMD5.equals("") && fileMD5.equals(urlMD5)) 
                                            // MD5 is correct
                                        {
                                            // Finished-Event auslösen
                                            for (DownloadProgressListener l: progressListeners) {
                                                l.setChecksum("");
                                                l.setValue(size);
                                                l.setStatus(DownloadProgressListener.STATUS_FINISHED);
                                            }
                                            ViewController.refreshMainProgress(); 
                                            setRunning(false);
                                        }else
                                        { // Error-MD5
                                            for (DownloadProgressListener l: progressListeners) 
                                            {
                                                l.setChecksum("");
                                                l.setErrorMessage("Error MD5 incorrect: fileMD5:'" + fileMD5 + "' urlMD5:'" + urlMD5 + "'");
                                                l.setStatus(DownloadProgressListener.STATUS_ERROR);
                                            }
                                            ViewController.refreshMainProgress(); 
                                            /*loadedbytes = 0;
                                            retryCount++;
                                            saveTo.delete();
                                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                                            if (retryCount < retryMax) 
                                            {
                                                startDownload();
                                                for (DownloadProgressListener l: progressListeners) 
                                                {
                                                    l.setStatus(DownloadProgressListener.STATUS_RUNNING);
                                                }
                                            }else
                                            {   
                                                DataController.getInstance().downloadsRunning.remove(url);
                                                loadedbytes = 0;
                                                retryCount = 0;
                                                outb.close();
                                                saveTo.delete();
                                            }*/
                                        }
                                }
                                else {
                                    // Pause-Event auslösen
                                    for (DownloadProgressListener l: progressListeners) {
                                        l.setStatus(DownloadProgressListener.STATUS_PAUSED);
                                    }
                                }


                            ViewController.refreshMainProgress(); 
                            //}catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            //  e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (SSLException e) {

                                try {
                                    loadedbytes = 0;
                                    retryCount++;
                                    outb.close();
                                    bos.close();
                                    saveTo.delete();

                                    if (retryCount < retryMax) {
                                        System.out.println("Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage() + "\n--> Attempt #" + retryCount + ": Retrying file '" + saveTo.getName() + "' in 2 seconds.");

                                        Thread.sleep(2000); // 2s
                                        startDownload();
                                    } else {
                                        // Error-Event auslösen
                                        for (DownloadProgressListener l: progressListeners) {
                                            l.setErrorMessage("Error retreiving network stream [" + e.getMessage() + "]");
                                            l.setStatus(DownloadProgressListener.STATUS_ERROR);
                                        }
                                        loadedbytes = 0;
                                        retryCount = 0;
                                        outb.close();
                                        bos.close();
                                        saveTo.delete();
                                    }
                                } catch (Exception e1) {
                                    e1.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();

                                // Error-Event auslösen
                                for (DownloadProgressListener l: progressListeners) {
                                    l.setErrorMessage("Error retreiving network stream [" + e.getMessage() + "]");
                                    l.setStatus(DownloadProgressListener.STATUS_ERROR);
                                }

                                try {
                                    loadedbytes = 0;
                                    retryCount = 0;

                                    // Ausgabe- und Netzwerk-Stream beenden, Zieldatei löschen
                                    bos.flush();
                                    bos.close();
                                    bis.close();
                                    outb.flush();
                                    outb.close();
                                    ins.close();
                                    saveTo.delete();
                                } catch (IOException e1) {}

                            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();

                                loadedbytes = 0;
                                retryCount = 0;
                                // Error-Event auslösen
                                for (DownloadProgressListener l: progressListeners) {
                                    l.setErrorMessage("Error accessing file '" + saveTo.getAbsolutePath() + "'");
                                    l.setStatus(DownloadProgressListener.STATUS_ERROR);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                });
                downloadThread.start();
            } else {
                String errMsg = "HTTP Error Status: " + rc + " " + con.getResponseMessage();
                for (DownloadProgressListener l: progressListeners) {
                    l.setErrorMessage(errMsg);
                    l.setStatus(DownloadProgressListener.STATUS_ERROR);
                }

                saveTo.delete();
                loadedbytes = 0;
                retryCount = 0;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            loadedbytes = 0;
            retryCount = 0;
            try {
                // Ausgabe- und Netzwerk-Stream beenden
                bos.flush();
                bos.close();
                bis.close();
                outb.flush();
                outb.close();
                ins.close();
            } catch (Exception e1) {}

            String errMsg = "Unknown Error";
            if (e instanceof MalformedURLException) {
                errMsg = "Invalid URL";
            } else if (e instanceof UnknownHostException) {
                errMsg = "Unable to resolve hostname '" + e.getMessage() + "'. Please check your network connection.";
            } else if (e instanceof IOException) {
                errMsg = e.getMessage(); //"Error retreiving network stream";
            }
            System.out.println(errMsg);

            // Error-Event auslösen
            for (DownloadProgressListener l: progressListeners) {
                l.setErrorMessage(errMsg);
                l.setStatus(DownloadProgressListener.STATUS_ERROR);
            }           
        }
    }
```

I am not able to reproduce the error every time and it seems like some machines will produce it more often like others. Maybe it is something with an false closed handle or something like that?

Comment: Try to put more tracing logs into your code. Especially where you abort a loop (if stop or paused). Date now could be replace with System.currentTime ..

Comment: Btw why do you get  con.getInputStream() twice?

Comment: You don't need all those flushes and closes. Just close the BufferedOutputStream and the BufferedInputStream. There's nothing here that would corrupt the data except possibly a resumed download if you didn't resume at the right place, or you didn't do the right closes when you get an exception. What *is* your exception handling?

Comment: i edited the first post and uploaded the whole function so that you can see the error handling.

Comment: i removed the double getInputStream(), was from a test. i also changed the date thing to currentTime.

Comment: The streams shall be closed in finally blocks, the code is then easier to read as you do not need to duplicate it in normal flow / exception flow. And as @EJP stated, the buffered stream shall close underlying stream as well, so you do not need to close these streams explicitelly.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a resumed download and the saved file isn't of the expected length, specifically if it is shorter, but it does exist, you have an unhandled error case. I don't know what's right for your situation but I wound be deleting the file and starting again.

And you need to make all the adjustments mentioned in my comment, if only for clarity.